# Why two DIVs can not be draggable under parent DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have written some code according to project requirement and in that I need to present notes that lets user to write.

The notes are draggable and can be moved in certain areas.

When I tried to add more than one note, only one note is able to be dragged, the rest are not able to be dragged.

The notes are comming under parent `DIV`. And each note has its own `DIV`. Please point out my mistakes and guide me. Thank you.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#draggable").draggable({
        containment : 'parent',
        handle: "p",
        start: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(221, 251, 120);');
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(227, 250, 150)');
        }
    });
    $("div, p").disableSelection();
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    width: 77vw;
    height: 87vh;
}

#draggable{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(227, 250, 150);
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#draggable p {
    cursor: move;
}

#draggable-header p{
    background: rgb(80, 80, 80);
    height: 30px;
    width: 300px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#draggable textarea{
    background: transparent;
    resize: none;
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: none;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-eGE6blurk5sHj+rmkfsGYeKyZx3M4bG+ZlFyA7Kns7E="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="wrap">
     <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
          <div id="draggable-header">
               <p class="ui-widget-header">Note name1</p>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <textarea placeholder="Message" id="w3review" class="ui-widget-header" name="w3review" rows="1" cols="2"></textarea>
     </div>

     <div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
          <div id="draggable-header">
               <p class="ui-widget-header">Note name2</p>
          </div>
     </div>
     <div>
          <textarea placeholder="Message" id="w3review" class="ui-widget-header" name="w3review" rows="1" cols="2"></textarea>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in html ID should be unique, you can't use same ID for more then one element.

change your Selector from `$("#draggable").draggable({` to `$(".ui-widget-content").draggable({` this will work correctly.

```
$(function () {
$(".ui-widget-content").draggable({
    containment : 'parent',
    handle: "p",
    start: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(221, 251, 120);');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).css('background-color', 'rgb(227, 250, 150)');
    }
  });
  $("div, p").disableSelection();
});
```

check here working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/designerPrasanna/6x0mf7k2/)

Comment: Yes its working perfectly now. Thank you.But I have one more confusion that when user click on ```add note``` the new note should come, which is coming but now its not draggable. any thoughts on that?

Comment: it's glad to hear it worked for you. and add note function is depends on what you wrote, that doesn't belong to this question. you can ask another question related to that. anyways happy coding:-)

Answer (score 1):

HTML id should be unique. Try rename second note's id and provide draggable interaction as well.

Comment: So should I write 10 different queries for 10 different notes?

Comment: you can use class instead of id @GamarChoba

Comment: After changing ID to Class, the output seems to be misbehaving. Only appears on the top of the screen.